# Are Weil divisors defined over any algebraic scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, intersection-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I notice that:

In fulton's book "Intersection Theory", $r$-cycles  are defined  in any algebraic scheme (see page 10). In particular, Weil divisors (i.e. cycles of codimension 1) are well defined.
But  In Hartshorne's book "Algebraic Geometry" says  that Weil  divisors are  defined only  over some noetherian integral schemes (see page 129). In fact Hartshorne define Weil divisors only  on a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular  in  codimension 1 (see page 130).

Which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's examine the definitions first. Here's Fulton's definitions:

> **B.1.1.** An *algebraic scheme* over a field $K$ is a scheme $X$, together with a morphism of finite type from $X$ to $\operatorname{Spec} K$.

> **B.1.2.** A *variety* is a reduced and irreducible (integral) algebraic scheme. A *subvariety* $V$ of a scheme $X$ is a reduced and irreducible closed subscheme of $X$.

> (p.10, section 1.3) Let $X$ be an algebraic scheme. A *$k$-cycle* on $X$ is a finite formal sum $$\sum n_i[V_i]$$ where the $V_i$ are $k$-dimensional subvarieties of $X$ and the $n_i$ are integers.

> (p.29, section 2.1) Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional variety. A *Weil divisor* on $X$ is an $(n-1)$ cycle on $X$.

And here's Hartshorne's:

> Let $X$ be a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular in codimension one. A *prime divisor* on $X$ is a closed integral subscheme of codimension one. A *Weil divisor* is an element of the free abelian group $\operatorname{Div} X$ generated by the prime divisors.

As you can see, the definitions are relatively close:

| Trait | Fulton | Hartshorne |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $X$ noetherian | Yes | Yes |
| $X$ finite type over a field | Yes | Not necessarily |
| $X$ integral | Yes | Yes |
| $X$ separated | Not necessarily | Yes |
| $X$ regular in codim 1 | Not necessarily | Yes |
| Elements are formal finite sums of integral closed subschemes | Yes | Yes |

The elements they have in common are some of the key features: working in a noetherian integral scheme and considering formal sums of integral closed subschemes.

If you compare the definitions to other sources like [the Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BE0) or [Vakil](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf), you can see that these key features are basically present in everyone's definition (Stacks generalizes a little to the locally noetherian situation, but adds the requirement that the sums be locally finite). The general idea remains the same, but some of the implementation details are a little different - that doesn't make any one of the definitions correct or wrong, just slightly better suited for different work.

Comment: Dear @KReiser, but  in Fulton's book $X$ is  not necessarily Noetherian neither  integral... Or   am I missing  something?

Comment: @Roxana According to the definitions which I copied in to the post from Fulton's text, when defining Weil divisors, $X$ is assumed to be a variety, aka an integral scheme of finite type over a field. Schemes of finite type over a field are definitely noetherian!

Comment: Dear @KReiser, Thank  you  for  the clarification! I did not  realise that Weil divisors were defined on a Variety... Well, on any algebraic scheme $X$ cycles  of codimension $1$ are well defined (see page 10, section 1.3), but  I can not call them  Weil  divisors, right? (But they have the same  definitions! but in different  type of schemes. It is a little strange for me)

Comment: @Roxana you're sort of falling in to the same trap as earlier - do you think there's some supreme arbiter of mathematics who will come and strike you down if you do something like this? When you use a phrase like "Weil divisor" or "variety", you need to make sure you're specific about what that means (there are, after all, different definitions it the literature) but after that as long as you're capturing the essential parts of the definition I don't think people will have cause to complain too much.

Comment: Dear @KReiser. I  understand :)! Thank you  for your explanations and clarifications! They are  very  useful!